# What's the most efficient way to find if a mac address is in range?

Tags: vb.net, ip

I have a large range of number of strings that are mac addresses. If they're in a certain range, I want to be able to go to a certain case statement.

For example, "78:A1:83:24:00:00 to 78:A1:83:24:0F:FF"

I have my code going so that it removes the last two hex and selects off that such as below:

```
 'remove last three characters
    mac = mac.TrimEnd()
    mac = mac.Substring(0, mac.Length - 3)

    'convert
    Select Case mac

        'Advidia
       Case "78:A1:83:40:00", "78:A1:83:40:01", "78:A1:83:40:02", "78:A1:83:40:03", _
             "78:A1:83:40:04", "78:A1:83:40:05", "78:A1:83:40:06", "78:A1:83:40:07", _
            "78:A1:83:40:08", "78:A1:83:40:09", "78:A1:83:40:0A", "78:A1:83:40:0B"
             ' it continues
            Return "VP-1"
```

But this just looks like I'm wasting space. What's a better way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MAC address is nothing more than a number represented by 6 bytes written in hexdecimal form.
So, converting the lower and upper limit of the MAC address could give you a manageable range of values to check with a single IF

```
Sub Main
    Dim lowRange = "78:A1:83:24:40:00"
    Dim upRange = "78:A1:83:24:40:FF"

    Dim startVal = GetValue(lowRange)
    Dim endVal = GetValue(upRange)
    Console.WriteLine(startVal)   ' 132635085258752
    Console.WriteLine(endVal)     ' 132635085259007

    Dim macToCheck = "78:A1:83:24:40:B0"
    Dim checkVal = GetValue(macToCheck)
    Console.WriteLine(checkVal)   ' 132635085258928

    if checkVal >= startVal AndAlso checkVal <= endVal Then
        ' VP-1
        Console.WriteLine("In range")
    End If

End SUb

Function GetValue(mac as String ) as Long
    Dim clearText = mac.Replace(":", "")
    Dim result
    Long.TryParse(clearText, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result)
    return result
End Function
```

Now, as an example to avoid a long list of IF you could use a Dictionary filled with your ranges and then apply a simple For Each logic to find your ranges

```
Sub Main
    Dim dc as New Dictionary(Of String, MacRange)()
    dc.Add("VP-1", new MacRange() with 
    { 
        .Lower = "78:A1:83:24:40:00", 
        .Upper = "78:A1:83:24:40:FF" 
    })

    dc.Add("VP-2", new MacRange() with 
    { 
        .Lower = "78:A1:83:24:41:00", 
        .Upper = "78:A1:83:24:41:FF" 
    })

    dc.Add("VP-3", new MacRange() with 
    { 
        .Lower = "78:A1:83:24:42:00", 
        .Upper = "78:A1:83:24:42:FF" 
    })

    Dim result = ""
    Dim macToCheck = "78:A1:83:24:42:B0"
    Dim checkVal = GetValue(macToCheck)
    'For Each k in dc
    '    Dim lower = GetValue(k.Value.Lower)
    '    Dim upper = GetValue(k.Value.Upper)
    '    if checkVal >= lower AndAlso checkVal <= upper Then
    '        result = k.Key
    '        Exit For
    '    End If
    'Next
    'Console.WriteLine(result)   ' VP-3

    ' The loop above could be replaced by this LINQ expression 
    Dim m = dc.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) checkVal >= GetValue(x.Value.Lower) AndAlso _
                                          checkVal <= GetValue(x.Value.Upper))
    If m IsNot Nothing Then
         Console.WriteLine(m.Key)  ' VP-3
    Else
         Console.WriteLine("Range not found")
    End If

End Sub

Class MacRange
    Public Lower as String
    Public Upper as String
End Class

Function GetValue(mac as String ) as Long
    Dim clearText = mac.Replace(":", "")
    Dim result
    Long.TryParse(clearText, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result)
    return result
End Function
```

Comment: I really like this solution. The problem is I have a large number of ranges and scenarios (i.e. a lot of case statements). What's a good way to convert this to a more large scale friendly way that isn't a multiple set of Ifs statements?

Comment: Using a dictionary and a custom class with lower and upper bound for mac addresses for values, then looping on the dictionary values to find the right range. Trying to write something to explain better

Comment: Sounds very promising! I haven't made a dictionary before, but first time for everything.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like a great resource. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there anything other than "Imports System.Linq" That I should be including? It's complaining saying that FirstorDefault isn't defined with a Missing Member exception.

Comment: Should have a reference to System.Core and add the Imports for Linq and System.Collections.Generic

Comment: Yeah, i have both of those. still getting "Public member 'FirstOrDefault' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,MacRange)' not found." Hmmm... Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Just for check, which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I had used a new function to create the dictionary. It wants the FirstOrDefault in that same function.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't existing functions that provide such utility. You could just split each string and create your ranges manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some sort of regex (Regular Expression) validation for various ranges.

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=mac%20address&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
will give you a good starting point.